# Multiple foreign key relationship to one table

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

How do you make a relationship between multiple foreign key values from one table to another table

**First Table:**

```
Item1a

Item1b

Item1c
```

**Second Table:**

```
ItemID

Description
```

Whereas `Item1a, Item1b and Item1c` gets their source from the **second table:** `ItemID`. Connecting them all in the relationship diagram doesn't change anything, how do I build their connection?

Thanks

Comment: You have to add the Second Table three time in the JOIN.

Comment: I already tried that, but you won't be able to add a table if you already added it once in the crystal report maker.

Comment: I am not Pro with Crystal report, but you can add same table with different alias. When you try to add the same table it asks you to create a new alias, say yes.

Comment: You should start here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need three different `JOIN` for the second table.

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM FirstTable f
<LEFT/INNER> JOIN SecondTable s1 ON s.ItemID = Item1a
<LEFT/INNER> JOIN SecondTable s2 ON s.ItemID = Item1b
<LEFT/INNER> JOIN SecondTable s3 ON s.ItemID = Item1c
```

Hope this help.

Comment: is there a way where you can configure this in the crystal report maker

Comment: To configure this in the Crystal Report designer, go to Database Expert and add the same table to the Selected Tables section 3 times.  Each time you add the table after the first it will warn you and ask if you want to create an alias.  Once you have done this, you go into Links and link each of the tables just like you would the first.